# stuck on database design for user management app

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm trying to write up a user management app, but getting confused about how to structure the database properly.

I think the database design would be structured something like this:

**Users**

- user_id
- first_name
- last_name
- email

**Accounts**

- account_id
- ldap_access
- drupal_access
- billing_app_access
- facebook_access

**Notes**

- note_id
- description
- date_added

And I believe the mapping would go like this:

One user can have one set of accounts (1:1)

One set of accounts can have many users (1:m)

One set of accounts can have many notes (1:m)

Many Notes can have Many Sets of Accounts (m:m)

Is this the correct way to structure the database? I'm really confused since I would like the applications fields be a boolean true/false for that particular user. (If they have an account on there or not), and the notes would correspond to EACH of the fields within the Accounts database. (ie: note_id:1 would correspond to user johndoe, application: facebook, note_description = "user no longer has facebook")

Does this make sense?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: wow try some modeling tool even mspaint is better than text :) how many users are you planning to keep in this base? i think it's way too complicated - remember about KISS principle, or later it will make you lots of trouble

Comment: Sorry about that Silx, it will be around 300 users. Are you stating KISS as in this could all be done in one table?

Comment: What do you mean, `One set of accounts can have many users (1:m)`? If user-account is 1-1, guess what: account-user is 1-1 too...

Comment: a 1:1 mapping always sounds a little suspect. And looking at the accounts table, I'm not sure it's modelled correctly. What if some magical, mystical, fifth account type needs adding in the future?

Comment: one table is not a good idea if u assume that your service list may change ie you will add stackoverflow_access column later, it's better to have other table called service (id, name), also if you plan to have one note per service - user then you should forget about this table, if u need full history of changes keep it, i will give you my expamle in few sec

Comment: @Konerak - I'm trying to state that a user would have multiple accounts, but since I have all those accounts as fields within the one Accounts table, I had it set that way.

Comment: Thanks Slix! I think that makes sense to me. Looking forward to the example! Sorry for being so uneducated on this subject!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mayby something like this:

[image]

I still don't understand all your needs.

Comment: Hi Silx, This seems like the best approach! I **REALLY** appreciate your help on this. It means so much!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this design (used in many system like Windows or Oracle)

Table
User
User-Role
Role
Access
Application
Note (still wonder what this for)

Role useful if you have many user with similar characteristic.